# Recruiting participants for study

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, sampling

I am planning to recruit participants in a college by advertising through posters, fliers, and the College Facebook. Is this method of recruitment considered clustered sampling, which is a type of probability sampling? I am afraid that if I make use of a convenience sampling, it will not be considered "probability sampling" and hence I will not be able to apply some statistical tests like regression analysis, factor analysis or ANOVA.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Could you tell us how you would compute the selection probabilities based on the advertising?  If you can do this objectively, then you are using probability sampling.

Comment: That is the dilemma here. Say I require 50 participants for this study, and through the ads, only 38 subjects sign up. I will have no choice but to select all of those who expressed interest. Is that still considered probability sampling?

Comment: How does the sampling method limit your statistical analysis? I would have thought that a sampling method would simply introduce a potential bias/limit conclusions. A bias you'd have to consider as a limitation, whatever you chose to call your sampling method

Comment: Probability sampling v.s. non-probability sampling. For the former, our population (sample) is supposed to be chosen at random. I presume that if I go the non-probability route (say snow-ball sampling), I will not be able to make use of those types of statistical analyses mentioned above. Please confirm.

Comment: @charles The sampling method imposes no limits whatsoever on the *analysis,* but it places severe restrictions on what the analysis *means.* With convenience samples it is next to impossible to validly infer anything about the population (unless the sample is almost as large as the population itself). Things like p-values and other probability-related outputs of standard statistical analyses are utterly without meaning unless one can (at least in principle) compute the prior chance that the sample one actually obtained would have arisen.

Comment: user39531: Suppose you require 50 participants and 100 answer the ads. Even if you take 50 from those 100, *that is not probability sampling* because you have no idea whether or to what degree those 100 people represent the population of interest. For example, suppose you recruit participants for a study of national political beliefs through an ad in a National Rifle Association newsletter or perhaps a Catholic church newsletter. No matter how many people answer that ad, you can be certain they are not characteristic of the country as a whole.

Comment: so is that not cluster sampling?

Comment: How should I approach the recruitment in that case in a school so that it is considered cluster sampling, that is a type of probability sampling to ensure that my sampling represents the whole population (in a school the pupils come from different locations, age group,background)

Comment: If in case more participants sign up, say 100, I can randomly choose 50 participants. But if only 38 participants sign up, I will have no choice to recruit all of the participants. How is this called - convenience sample? which is truly not probability sample. My question is how to approach the recruitment process in that case so that it turns out to be a probability sampling? Thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

First, I address your question about whether what you are doing could be cluster sampling.

The answer is, "No." From *Bayesian Data Analysis* 3rd ed., chapter 8, pg. 210, final paragraph under *Cluster sampling* header:

> In cluster sampling, $N$ units are divided into $K$ clusters, and
>   sampling proceeds in two stages. First, a sample of $J$ clusters is drawn, and second, a sample of $n_j$ units is drawn from the $N_j$ units within each sampled cluster $j = 1,\ldots,J$.

You are not dividing the units up into discrete clusters, and you are not sampling the two stages described above. Therefore, you are not using cluster sampling.

Second, I address your more general question about whether this is probability sampling.

The answer again is, "Probably not."

From the Wikipedia entry on [probability and nonprobability sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Probability_and_nonprobability_sampling):

> A **probability sampling** is one in which every unit in the population
>   has a chance (greater than zero) of being selected in the sample, and
>   this probability can be accurately determined.

The college students in your sample will be selected from those who saw the ads, decided to do the study, and actually completed it. You will likely not have any information to build a probability model describing that process, in which case this is nonprobability sampling, in which there is no accurate method for estimating the probability of selection.

As @whuber said, "The sampling method imposes no limits whatsoever on the analysis, but it places severe restrictions on what the analysis means." In addition to this, I suggest that you record how your subjects heard about the study and include it as a covariate in your analysis. It doesn't matter if the recruitment effect is not "statistically significant". You should include those covariates because it is an adequate summary of how the data was collected, and will make the missing data within the recruitment type strata ignorable. See BDA3 chapter 8 for details.

Comment: Wait for a bit before you act on what I say. I may be wrong. Follow the question along and see if anyone else supplies a better answer before checking mine or upvoting it. As for convenience samples, it's fine to use them so long as you are honest about what inferences you may draw from the analysis. If you are new to xval, welcome.

Comment: That said, I am fairly confident that I am right.